# How to get jQuery/AJAX final URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When I run `$.get` or `.load` in jQuery, the request seems to follow 302 redirects perfectly fine and gives me ultimate response, which I can use in the callback for `$.get` or which plugs into the `this` element for `.load`.

While I obviously have the original URL since I am in control of the string that's entered as the first argument in `$.get` or `.load` (it would also be helpful if I could get this directly in the callback to simplify things), how can access the final (after redirect) URL in the callback?

I suspect that it would be in the XMLHttpRequest object, for which I have [found the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794140/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-final-url-retrieved-by-an-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I'm not sure (and Googling hasn't gotten me anywhere), but what about this unorthodox solution?

    var hiddenIframe = $('').attr({ style: 'display: none;' }).appendTo('body');

    hiddenIframe.attr({ src: 'http://www.direct-me.com' });

    hiddenIframe.load(function() {

        alert(hiddenIframe.attr('src'));

    });

Basically it just makes a hidden iframe, and then goes to your URL, and the callback for load *should* tell you the final URL.</del>

It appears you cannot. You can get the original `src`, but then you cannot due to security issues.

Comment: Is there any reason you're convinced why this is impossible? After all, I understand that you can get the response headers anyway (http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders-method), so it doesn't seem as if the browser prevents you from accessing that information. Also, cross site security prevents you from making an AJAX request to, say http://facebook.com/delete-my-profile, but I don't see why it would be involved here.

Comment: @Steven I'm not convinced, and I hope someone proves me otherwise.

Comment: I'm using Rails, which uses the `redirect_to` method to stop script execution and deliver the location header. I redefined the function to send a text string containing a URL or URL segment in XHR cases or if an xhr=1 hidden variable is set (since, for instance, the Form plugin doesn't actually use an XHR request), and to parse the returned content client-side, redirecting if it parses as a URL. Semantically, it may be better just to custom define a header and send the redirect URL there, but this current approach hasn't produced complications and I presume has better compatibility.